# ZFS interpret output of zdb -S tank

Tags: zfs, deduplication

I wanted to know if it would pay it out for me to activate the zfs deduplication so I ran the command
`zdb -S tank` but know I need some help to interpret the output.

```
Simulated DDT histogram:

bucket              allocated                       referenced
______   ______________________________   ______________________________
refcnt   blocks   LSIZE   PSIZE   DSIZE   blocks   LSIZE   PSIZE   DSIZE
------   ------   -----   -----   -----   ------   -----   -----   -----
     1    49.2M   6.15T   6.15T   6.14T    49.2M   6.15T   6.15T   6.14T
     2     352K   42.0G   42.0G   42.0G     725K   86.3G   86.3G   86.4G
     4    7.99K    913M    913M    916M    37.7K   4.20G   4.20G   4.21G
     8    1.43K    161M    161M    161M    14.6K   1.58G   1.58G   1.58G
    16      623   67.1M   67.1M   67.4M    12.2K   1.32G   1.32G   1.33G
    32       73   7.37M   7.37M   7.43M    2.65K    268M    268M    270M
    64      717   4.23M   4.23M   7.46M    48.3K    392M    392M    611M
   128        4    257K    257K    266K      689   40.9M   40.9M   42.6M
   256        2    128K    128K    133K      802   57.8M   57.8M   59.3M
   512        2      1K      1K   10.7K    1.37K    703K    703K   7.32M
    4K        1    128K    128K    128K    7.31K    935M    935M    934M
   16K        1    512B    512B   5.33K    20.0K   10.0M   10.0M    107M
   64K        1    128K    128K    128K    93.0K   11.6G   11.6G   11.6G
  512K        1    128K    128K    128K     712K   89.0G   89.0G   88.9G
 Total    49.6M   6.19T   6.19T   6.18T    50.9M   6.34T   6.34T   6.33T

dedup = 1.02, compress = 1.00, copies = 1.00, dedup * compress / copies = 1.03
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spend many gigabytes of RAM for a 1.02x difference? I wouldn't.

Comment: So do I interpret the data correct that ZFS would be able to compress / dedup  the data by only 2%?

Comment: The numbers are rounded, but yes. And honestly I wouldn't touch dedup at all regardless, even for 2x. The performance hit and additional RAM requirements just make it not worth it. Disk is cheap. Time is expensive.

Comment: Do you want to post this as an answer than I can approve your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that you should look at this histogram. The first and most obvious one is the `dedup` expression at the end of it. There's nothing much to say about it since it's simple mathematics. In your case deduplication will only provide a space saving of 2%, and since you don't use compression (which you should in first place, because it saves space and gives you performance because I/O is much more costly than CPU time with an efficient algorithm like LZ4), that's the marginal gain that you'll have after enabling deduplication: 2~3%.

Deduplication starts to be valuable when the effective space saving is higher than 2.0 and your storage subsystem is so expensive, that memory and CPU are OK to be wasted just to handle deduplication. We are talking about Enterprise NVMe pools for example.

*But at which cost this come?*

That's the second thing that I've mentioned. The first hit will be in your RAM. You'll need to store the deduplication tables on RAM. If there's no RAM to hold it, the system will just crash and you'll be unable to mount the pool. There's some advancements with newer versions of ZFS (Like OpenZFS 2.0), but I'm not aware if anything has changed regarding this.

With this in mind, you just get the total number of blocks, which is the last line of the first column: `49.6M`

Since each dedup table needs 320 bytes you just multiply the number of blocks by the required space for a given dedup table and you'll get the needed amount of RAM:

```
49.6M * 320 bytes = 15.872MB ~ 15.5GB
```

So you'll waste almost **16GB** of system RAM just to deduplicate your non-dedup-friendly data. That 16GB will be removed from vital parts of the system, like ARC, that simply speedup your pool.

So, no. Deduplication does not worth except if:

- You have extremely expensive storage subsystem
- Your data can be easily deduplicated